# DependencyInjection: Load classes from directory

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

We're using DependencyInjection and tags to load classes and add them to a chain. I like to expand the functionality with auto loading from a directory.

Directory structure:
X\
  Y\
    MyBundle\
      Example\
        HelloWorldExample.php

I want to add all classes to the chain which are in the Example directory from all bundles.
Something like the Command or Doctrine2 component do with the Command and Entity directories.

I can't find anything on Google (or I'm using the wrong keywords...). Someone can help?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I already use the Dependency Injection component in my Symfony2 application. At this moment I load classes with tagging services (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html) but I want to expand this functionality with auto loading this classes if they are in a specific directory (in the above structure it would be Example).

I don't want to iterate through directories / files.

Comment: You wish to autoload php classes? Why not simply instantiate them via calling them by their namespace? Or you need to load services (definitions)?

Comment: Some oldfashioned way like iterating through directory, find files, check if readable and classes and instantiate?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I guess the OP want to autoload each file in certain directory without specifying all of them?

Comment: There should be a "Symfony2 way" but I don't seem to find it. @Royal I do want to autoload them and put them in a chain so services can use them (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html).

Comment: Why not use symfony then? :) It has pretty much big library for dependency injection, you either need to use it, or copy it someway to use "the symfony2 way". The other way around is to instantiate everything in the directory and pass it to the object constructor, if everything is needed ofcourse. Or to the chain.

Comment: I am now curious to see what's in those files you wish to autoload?

Comment: I'm using Symfony2, and I use the Dependency Injection component. I already use dependency injection with tagging services but I want to expand the functionality by auto loading classes if they are in a specific directory in a Bundle. EDIT: I added some more info in the OP

Comment: Consider updating your question with a specific example of what you like your dependency injection services file to look like cause it is still not clear to me what you are trying to do.  You can build a service definition programitically, have it scan a directory and have it inject each class in the directory but is that what you really want?

Comment: @Cerad, yes that is what I want :-)

Comment: Well, I think it's going to be a bit involved.  Probably need a compiler pass.  Maybe start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want this functionality? Might have a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

Composer is perfect for this (and for loading external dependencies) - see https://getcomposer.org/

To start, create a `composer.json` file in your root folder:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "X": "src/" }
  }
}
```

Run `composer update` to create the autoload files, then `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in your PHP file.

Given that you have a file `src/X/Y/MyClass.php` defining the class `\X\Y\MyClass`, the definition should be automatically loaded when you call e.g. `$x = new \X\Y\MyClass();`.

Comment: I already use composer to download and auto load bundles in the vendor directory. This isn't the answer to my question because I want to load classes with the Symfony Dependency Injection component. EDIT: I added some more info in the OP

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood the question. I don't think this is a common enough need to exist as a ready-to-use package, but for an example on how Symfony does it, take a look at Doctrine2 code for the AnnotationDriver: https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php#L194 - this is used for loading the Doctrine entities, and can possibly be reused in your scenario?